# AngularJS $rootScope.$emit not Firing the Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to fire a directive based on demand using a service. Below is the directive code.

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule').service('DOMService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    this.Manipulate = function () {
        $rootScope.$emit('manipulateDOM');
    };
}]).directive('domDirective', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: 'false',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            $rootScope.$on("manipulateDOM", function () {
                alert("Entered......");
                //  element.find('#DirectiveLable').css('background-color', 'red')
                // element.find('#DirectiveLable').css('height', '100')
            });
        },
    };
}]);
```

My HTML like below

```
<div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <dom-directive>
            <label id="DirectiveLable">Click Here</label>
        </dom-directive>
    </div>
```

I am calling the service like below inside my Angular Controller

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller('CitizenRelationAccordionController', ['$scope', '$q', '$attrs', 'DOMService',
    function ($scope, $q, $attrs, DOMService) {
       DOMService.Manipulate();
    }
 ]);
```

Issue is that eventhough DOMService is firing, it's not invoking the directive method where alert has written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you missed the `[]` in the module declaration: [here](http://jsbin.com/haquxonola/edit?html,js,output) is a working example from what you wrote.

Hope this could help,

Dario

Comment: It's working in your example. Actually I have separate files, DomDirective.js and CitizenRelationAccordionController.js for directive and controllers. Module declarion done inside DomDirective.js as angular.module('MyModule', []);
var app = angular.module('MyModule');
app.service('DOMService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) { etc...      JS Ref. has been made in a sequence like below.   <script src="~/Scripts/DomDirective.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CitizenRelationAccordionController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.So still looking on it.

Comment: Cool. This new sample code given visibility to "<div ng-controller="CitizenRelationAccordionController">". Actually I didn't refer the controller any where across my page which caused this issue. Once added a mere controller reference, all started working. Thanks @Dario for the help.